# ASP.NET impersonation from code (C#) and connected SQL Server Express user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-express, impersonation

I'm having trouble with ASP.NET impersonation from code (C#) and using SQL Server Express:

I'm able to impersonate successfully and connect to SQL Server, however executing `SELECT CURRENT_USER` returns `guest` instead of `TestUser_001`.

Note: I've tried impersonation with `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT` and then with `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` when calling `LogonUser` - the result remains the same. Account from which I'm executing this impersonation code has `Act as part of the operating system` set. Tested under IIS Express (F5 from Visual Studio 2013). I never logged in interactively as `TestUser_001` and connected to SQL Server Express instance - there is no `MY_DOMAIN\TestUser_001` under `Security\Logins` - would like for this to happen automatically when using the code.

```
using (var impersonation = new ImpersonationHelper("TestUser_001", "MY_DOMAIN", "pass"))
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MY_DOMAIN\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;"))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CURRENT_USER";
            var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the rudimentary `ImpersonationHelper` implementation:

```
public class ImpersonationHelper : IDisposable
{
    public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    public const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8;
    public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int LogonUser(
        string lpszUsername,
        string lpszDomain,
        string lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        ref IntPtr phToken
    );

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int DuplicateToken(
        IntPtr hToken,
        int impersonationLevel,
        ref IntPtr hNewToken
    );

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    private readonly WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext_;

    public ImpersonationHelper(string username, string domain, string password)
    {
        var token = IntPtr.Zero;
        var token_duplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (RevertToSelf())
        {
            if (LogonUser(username, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
            {
                if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref token_duplicate) != 0)
                {
                    var temp_windows_identity = new WindowsIdentity(token_duplicate);
                    impersonationContext_ = temp_windows_identity.Impersonate();

                    if (impersonationContext_ != null)
                    {
                        CloseHandle(token);
                        CloseHandle(token_duplicate);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(token);

        if (token_duplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(token_duplicate);

        throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to impersonate as {0}\\{1}.", username, domain));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        impersonationContext_.Undo();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is ImpersonationHelper? Does the constructor already perform impersonation or do you need to call some method first?

Comment: `ImpersonationHelper` already does impersonation. `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` returns `My_DOMAIN\TestUser_001` when called after `ImpersonationHelper`, before connecting to SQL Express.

Comment: What does `SELECT SUSER_SNAME();` return?

Comment: `SELECT SUSER_SNAME();` does return `MY_DOMAIN\TestUser_001`, however the user login is not listed under **Security\Logins**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Dan Guzman - SQL Server MVP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711162/dan-guzman-sql-server-mvp) and all others that helped with this question. I guess I'll mark this as an answer since the impersonation works and correct user is reported by SQL Server.